# How to play an alarm sound on Android via Push Notif regardless of Device locked or App killed without Foreground Service/Alarm Manager?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building an emergency security Android App. One of the important requirements is to play an Alarm sound from a push notification. This happens very rarely so most likely the App won't be running (maybe force stopped) and device might be locked or in sleep mode.

I am using FCM to send a push notification like this:

```
public class NotificationManager extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        playAlarmSound();

    }
}
```

And my Service looks like this:

```
<service
    android:name=".notification.NotificationManager"
    android:directBootAware="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

However, I only receive the notification if the Device is not locked.
How can ensure that happens?

I have seen some posts to use an Alarm Manager & Foreground Services - but I don't want to be constantly running and draining battery for an infrequent (but extremely important) usecase?

Comment: "I only receive the notification if the Device is not locked" -- how are you determining this? For example, if it is because your sound does not play, perhaps the issue is in how you are playing the sound.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thanks for your reply - No as soon I as unlock the phone the sound goes off.

Comment: Also I have a log which shows up - which shows up exactly when I unlock the device.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [custom sound](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#:%7E:text=in%20%23rrggbb%20format.-,sound,-string) so you can play the alarm sound. Set it to [high priority](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) so FCM will attempt to deliver it immediately even if the device is in Doze mode.

However, if you still consider using Alarm Manager, you can check out these posts about battery usage:

- [Android: correct way to use AlarmManager without draining battery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14076571/20447561)
- [About alarmManager and perfomance/battery issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293244/20447561)